# SaveAs specific file name with same path as original on SharePoint

Tags: excel, vba, save-as

I have a xlsm that I want every user to first run a macro that SavesAs
ThisWorkbook.Path & "_" & Format(Now(), "yy-mm-dd") & "_Tills.xlsm", FileFormat:=52

The code works on OneDrive document.

```vb
Sub Save_Workook_NewName()

ThisWorkbook.saveAs FileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "_" & Format(Now(), "yy-mm-dd") & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52

End Sub
```

On SharePoint, I am now getting

> Runtime error 1004: Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed.

because the file is stored on my "Tills" group SharePoint page, the expected results is a new XLSM file titled: "Tills_19-10-29.xlsm"

I have tried all sorts of code but the more complicated it got, the more intense the errors.

Comment: all i can see is that you're missing "/" after your `.path`.  Try inspecting the path to be certain, e.g., `debug.print thisworkbook.path`.

Comment: this seems to have worked well except excel gets stuck on a modal saying "processing" after this runs. The new spreadsheet shows up in sharepoint but excel has to be force quit and relaunched thus defeating the point. is there something this is getting stuck on?

Comment: Don't save directly to any network locations. It's an issue I've seen a few times. If you `FileCopy` it to the network, it goes much faster